# I would like to open the dialog when RecyclerView is clicked

Tags: listview, android-recyclerview, dialog

I would like to open the dialog when the RecyclerView is clicked.

But if I click the view of RecyclerView, the app is turned off.

Why is this happening?

I am watching the `//click event` part. Can I not fix it here? Or how do I fix it?

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView aurthorText;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        aurthorText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.aurthorText);
    }
}

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private int resourceId;
    private List<RecyclerModel> dataList;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<RecyclerModel>dataList){
        this.context=context;
        this.resourceId=resourceId;
        this.dataList=dataList;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resourceId,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        RecyclerModel recyclerModel = dataList.get(position);
        holder.aurthorText.setText(recyclerModel.getAurthor());
//        Toast.makeText(context, "click checking", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // click event
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, Plzfinish.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```